# Global class in node?

Tags: node.js

Global class?
I'd like to use a module in 2 other modules. And use defaults.
Then update the module after application is initialized (and connected to DB).
How this can be achieved?

Example use case:
Logger module is started with default configuration. It will fetch custom one from the database after database is connected.
Database module is using same logger (using default configuration until it gets configuration from that same database).

In many other languages I could create a class, then use instances of it and finally update class (not the instance) with new configuration. Updated values will be shared across the instances.

Some ideas that came into my mind:

- Maybe I am thinking about it wrong way?
- Can I use global variables?
- I can use a local shared resource (file for example) to trigger change after startup is completed and connections are established/configuration fetched.

Another problem: How to avoid strong coupling between the modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe I am thinking about it wrong way?

Right or wrong isn't really black and white here.  It's more about benefits of modularity.

> Can I use global variables?

You can, but you probably shouldn't.

Modularity in nodejs offers all sorts of benefits.  Using a global variable creates a global environment dependency that breaks some of the fundamental tenets of modularity.

Instead, it generally makes more sense to create a single module that encapsulates the shared instance that you wish to use.  When that module is initialized, it creates the shared instance and stores it locally in its own module level variable.  Then, when other modules `require()` or `import` this module, it exports that shared instance.  In this way you both retain the modularity and all the benefits of it and you get a common, shared instance that everyone who wants to can use.

The only downside?  One line of code is required in any module that wants to use the shared resource to import that shared resource.  That one line of code helps you retain all the benefits of modularity while still getting access to a shared resource.

> I can use a local shared resource (file for example) to trigger change after startup is completed and connections are established/configuration fetched.

It isn't clear what you mean by this.  Any modular, shared resource (without
globals) as described above can capture a configuration and preserve that configuration change.

> How to avoid strong coupling between the modules?

This is indeed one of the reasons to avoid globals as it creates strong coupling.  Any module that exports or shares (in any way) some shared resource creates some level of coupling.  The code using the shared resource has to know what the interface is to the shared resource and that cannot be avoided in order to use it.  You can often take advantage of existing interfaces (like eventEmitters) in order to avoid reinventing a lot of new interface, but the caller still needs to know what common interface is being used and how.